# UniqueValidator in drf

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

my model has a field:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

in serializer, I am trying to raise a unique validation error

```
name = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Department.objects.all(),
                                        message=("Name already exists"))])
```

but it does not work, because the data comes to the serializer in this format `name: {en: "drink"}`, in db fields are populated with `drink` only.

I can raise an error in the `create` method, but I want to raise the error on the serializer. appreciate any advice. I'm in a hurry. sorry for any inconvenience.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly suggest that you use Django Rest Framework's Serializer [Field-Level Validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation), which allows you to do custom validation for your field.

like the following:

```py
    name = serializers.CharField()
    ...
    def validate_name(self, value):
        # I assumed that you will that the string value, is a JSON object.
        entered_name = json.loads(value).get('en', None)
        if entered_name and Department.objects.filter(name__exact=entered_name).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Name already exists!")
        # You need to return the value in after validation.
        return value
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this below your meta class in Serializers.py as it will raise error saying error name must be unique

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel

    fields= ('name',) 
    extra_kwargs = {
                'name': {
                    'validators': [
                        UniqueValidator(
                            queryset=YourModelName.objects.all()
                        )
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to use `UniqueValidator` so I hacked `UniqueTogetherValidator`.

Like this;

import it:

`from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator`

then:

```py
class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NameOfModel
        fields = ['id', 'name']
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=NameOfModel.objects.all(),
                fields=['name']
            )
        ]
```

In case you want the name field to be unique.

Reference: [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator)

Comment: I think this is not doing what you are expecting. Your UniqueTogether fields are "id" and "name". ID is, by definition, always going to be unique, so it together with *anything* will still be unique. You could have id: 1, name: "My name" and id: 2, name: "My name" and it would pass your validation. Not sure why UniqueValidator wasn't woking for you, but in case you had it in the wrong place, it goes in the serializer field definition, not in the Meta class.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between these two methods, they both worked for me:

```
name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                queryset=YourModel.objects.all(),
                lookup="iexact",
                message=("This name already exists."),
            ),
        ],
    )
```

or

```
name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
validators = [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Yourodel.objects.all(),
                fields=['name'],
                message=("This name already exists."),
            )
        ]
```